# Mode Expansions of World-Sheet Fermion Fields

Tags: string-theory, string

Recently I'm studying superstrings by the Book written by B & B & S. I have a quick problem about the mode expansions of world-sheet supersymmetric fermion fields in Chapter 4. The mode expansions for open strings, (4.52) and (4.53) seems to be different from the bosonic case (2.62), and the mode expansions for closed strings, (4.59) and (4.60) seems to be diiferent from the bosonic case (2.40) and (2.41). It seems that there're no momentum terms and I don't know why. May be the momentums cannot be Grassmann numbers? But why? Thank you!